# Combobox default value for new item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have 2 comboboxs that has it's itemssource bound to 2 lists which are in a listview. This all works fine however when I add a new new item to the list the combobox values are blank and I want them to show me "All Zones" for one and "All Facies" in the other. How do I get this to work? I have tried many examples but all want me to use the "IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" to be true or the SelectedIndex to 0 however this also sets the current combobox values to the SelectedIndex which is not what I want I only want it if the combobox is blank. Can anyone please help me?

**Combobox's inside the ListView**

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" x:Name="zoneComboBox" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="20" Width="80" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Zones, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Zone}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <TextBlock Text="Zones" FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamily}" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}" x:Name="faciesComboBox" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="20" Width="80" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Facies, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Facie}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <TextBlock Text="Facies" FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamily}" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn>
```

**Add new rule method**

```
private void AddRuleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rules.Add(new GeologicalAnalysisRule());
    }
```

**Observable Collection (Edit)**

```
private ObservableCollection<GeologicalAnalysisRule> rules;

    public RuleSetterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rules = new ObservableCollection<GeologicalAnalysisRule>();
        Rules.Add(new GeologicalAnalysisRule());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GeologicalAnalysisRule> Rules
    {
        get { return rules; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, rules)) return;
            rules = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using private variable rules use Property Rules in the button click event.

```
private void AddRuleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rules.Add(new GeologicalAnalysisRule());
}
```

Comment: Just a quick curious question, is there any possible way to do this with data triggers at all or anything similar? Or dot hey just replace the existing values you have and ignore any current stored value?